# Images can't be downloaded programmatically from some websites

Tags: c#, asp.net, node.js, image, download

I can't download images directly from some websites. downloading operation from these sites has really random result and i have to retry each image over 10 times, and gain probably with some fail.

But when i visit that image inside the website content from the browser, the browser can download it at the first try and if i don't get that url by visiting via browser (by programming) then can't be downloaded even by the browser!

Try to download
`http://img7.irna.ir/1393/13931205/81518080/81518080-6295620.jpg`

***This webpage is not available*** The server returns `ECONNREFUSED` for the first try

Again, it can be success at the next retries (press `f5` in the browser )

**Reproducing `not available` in firefox:**

1. visit `irna.ir`
2. copy an image `url`
3. clear browser cache and cookies and ** close the browser **
4. open the browser and past that `url` directly in address bar
5. ** This webpage is not available **
6. visit the main page again
7. past that `url` in address bar and now image is available!

Thanks

Comment: It's simple: the website does not work properly, there seem to be major technical problems.

Comment: why when you visit images inside the page via browsers everything works fine?

Comment: Most of the images are loading extremely slowly or not at all. I doubt that should be called "fine".

Comment: It's very fast, visiting inside the country. it's location specific and is different from this problem **`not available`**